# How to optimize property array map

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Here i have Two arrays,

```
var Usercar = [
            {_id: 1, name: bmw, color: red},
            {_id: 2, name: Ford, color: black},
            {_id: 3, name: Volkswagen, color: black},
          ]

var Userfavorite = [1,3]
```

I want to show user favorite cars using map,like

```
            Usercar.map((car,index)=>{
                  Userfavorite.map(re=>{
                    if (car._id === re)
                    {
                     <p>{car.name}</p>
                    }
                  })
                })
```

My question is, This mapping will effects my JSX page ?, because i have multiple mapping like this in a page and how to optimize this mapping

I saw slow page load currently

Comment: can you change userCar structure to object instead of an array ? then you can simply loop over userFavourite array and get values from userCar.

Comment: Yes i got  you, but i have more stuffs on Usercar's array :(

Comment: This userCar array comes from any api ? or you locally build it ?

Comment: locally build  :)

Comment: Then you should build it as an object with id as key, then you can simply loop over userFavourite array and get respective value from userCar object. so it will be O(n)

Comment: if you dont mind please give your idea as an answer ,then it will helps me a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209977/discussion-between-harry-edward-and-code-maniac).

Comment: How did you identify this loop as the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: not this one, i have multiple like this in a page :( so i asked how to optimize

Comment: These loops then :)

Answer (score 3):

If there are multiple places where these mappings are required, I might consider converting the `Usercar` to a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). So then only one looping will be required, reducing complexity to O(n).

```
const userCarMap = new Map(Usercar.map(car => [car._id, car]));
// Map(3) {1 => {…}, 2 => {…}, 3 => {…}}



Userfavorite.map(fav => {
 const carInfo = userCarMap.get(fav);
 return <p>{carInfo.name}</p>
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var Usercar = [
            {_id: 1, name: 'bmw', color: 'red'},
            {_id: 2, name: 'Ford', color: 'black'},
            {_id: 3, name: 'Volkswagen', color: 'black'},
          ]

var Userfavorite = [1,3]

const convertArrayToObject = (array, key) => {
  const initialValue = {};
  return array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item[key]] = item; 
    return obj;
  }, initialValue);
};

var result = 
  convertArrayToObject(
    Usercar,
    '_id',
  );
  
console.log(Userfavorite.map(x => '<p>'+result[x].name+'</p>'));
```

Comment: It's probably better to use a Map nowadays rather than an object but it's still a good solution. A Map is just more modern.

Comment: I'm assuming these arrays are large if we are talking about performance... the destructuring `obj` into a new object is a bit memory thrashy.

Comment: `obj[item[key]] = item; return obj`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **filter**, **includes** and **map** method so that it will have a complexity of **O(n)** instead of **O(n²)** like so:

```
Usercar.filter(item => Userfavorite[item._id] != undefined)
    .map((car,index)=>{
    return (
        <p>{car.name}</p>
    )
});
```

**UPDATE**
Changed **.includes** to a simple check of existence

Comment: Thanks alot for you answer dear , will check :)

Comment: `filter()` -> `.includes()` is still `O(n^2)` since you have to do an iteration every iteration.

Comment: @VLAZ here filter,includes then mapping, do you have any better idea  ?

Comment: @HarryEdward check my updated answer. it is now **O(n)**

Comment: It's `O(n)` but it's also wrong. `Userfavorite[item._id]` will not give you the correct item - you're using the ID as n index, but with OP's example `_id = 3` would fail, even if it's present in `Userfavorite` because the array only has two items, and fetching index `3` will not find the item with value `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Usercar = [
  { _id: 1, name: "bmw", color: "red" },
  { _id: 2, name: "Ford", color: "black" },
  { _id: 3, name: "Volkswagen", color: "black" }
];

var Userfavorite = [1, 3];

var res = Usercar.filter(car => Userfavorite.includes(car._id))
      .map(item => item.name);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is still `O(n^2)` since `.includes` does another `O(n)` iteration within the `O(n)` from the `.filter`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly loop on Userfavorite. You just need check if id exists and return JSX.

```js
var Usercar = [
  {_id: 1, name: bmw, color: red},
  {_id: 2, name: Ford, color: black},
  {_id: 3, name: Volkswagen, color: black},
]

var Userfavorite = [1,3]

Usercar.map((car, index) => Userfavorite.includes(car._id) ? <p> { car.name } </p> : null);
```

Comment: @VLAZ what about this answer :)

Comment: Still `O(n^2)`. Again, `.includes` is `O(n)` and it's executed with every of the `O(n)` callbacks of `.map`. So, it's a nested loop.

Comment: @HarryEdward My best guess would be `O(n*m)` where `n` is `Usercar`'s length and `m` is `Userfavourite`'s length

Comment: Right, `O(n*m)` is more accurate. Point is it's a nested loop. Without removing the nested looping, the complexity is going to be a lot more than really needed.

Comment: @VLAZ We can join `Userfavorite` and inside `.map` check for string's indexOf or includes. That will go to `O(n+m)` But I'm not sure if that is really that performant

Comment: Making a lookup table of `Usercar` has an upfront cost of `O(n)` but then individual lookups are `O(1)`, so running `Userfavorite.map()` using the lookup will be a total of `O(m)' only. If repeat lookups are needed, then this is probably the way to go.

Comment: @VLAZ However, if the structure updates based on userInput or anything else, it adds overhead of maintaining the table. Accepted, with proper structure it will be more performant, but the question is, what are we saving? This looks like a micro-optimization to me, tbh

Comment: I'm not really sure what the slowdown is, to be honest. If you need to do A LOT of loops based on also looping to find an item in `Usercar`, then a lookup table solves that. But I've no idea whether that's the case or if time complexity of algorithms is even the root cause of it. We need the bigger picture here. I'm just throwing suggestions since most replies were not much of an improvement over OP's solution in terms of complexity.

Comment: think if i have more than 5 map in a page, defiantly it will effects the performance , i think

Comment: @HarryEdward If you have an array of 1 Billion, improper looping would cause you to loose a couple of sec max. Usually, you will not have such a huge array. So it depends on number of times your looping function will be called. This, as said by VLAZ, will be resolved using a proper data structure. But just focusing on loop will buy you few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification dear Rajesh and @VALAZ